# Join and compare 2 queries of 2 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is probably a quite trivial question for many here but I am not used to write sub queries and joins, so I hope someone want to help.

I have two tables: new_road and old_roads.

These two queries sum up the length of the roads belonging to a specific road number.

```
SELECT new_road.nummer, SUM(new_road.length) FROM road_table.road GROUP BY new_road.nummer

SELECT old_road.nummer, SUM(ST_length(old_road.geom)) FROM old_road_table.old_road GROUP BY old_road.nummer
```

I wish to have a result table where these two queries are joined so I can compare the new and old summed length for each road number.

Like

```
old.nummer old.length new.nummer new.lenght
2345       10.3       2345       10.5      
2346       578.2      2346       600
2347       54.2       NULL       NULL
NULL       NULL       2546       32.2
```

I think some version of an outer join is needed because there will be a road numbers in the old_road table that does not exist in the new.road table and i would like to see them too.

Appreciate any advice

Edit:

After advice from below did I came up with this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT new_road.nummer, SUM(new_road.length) FROM road_table.road GROUP BY new_road.nummer) new_table
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT old_road.nummer, SUM(ST_length(old_road.geom)) FROM old_road_table.old_road GROUP BY old_road.nummer) old_table
ON new_road.nummer = old_road.nummer
```

But each time I run it I get missing FROM-clause entry. When I run each sub query individually they work. I have crosschecked with the documentation and it look OK to me, but clearly I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [FULL OUTER JOIN](http://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/joins.php)

This is not the exact output you requested but you don't need to display the nummer twice.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(new_road.nummer,old_road.nummer)nummer,
    new_road.length,
    old_road.length
FROM (
    SELECT new_road.nummer
        ,SUM(new_road.length) length
    FROM road_table.road
    GROUP BY new_road.nummer
) new_road 
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT old_road.nummer
        ,SUM(ST_length(old_road.geom))length
    FROM old_road_table.old_road
    GROUP BY old_road.nummer
) old_road ON
    old_road.nummer = new_road.nummer
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried yours and the the other answers I got. But each time I run it I get missing FROM-clause entry. When I run the each sub query by it self they work. I have crosschecked with the documentation and it looks OK to me, but clearly I am missing something here.
<br> 
SELECT *
(SELECT new_road.nummer, SUM(new_road.length) FROM road_table.road GROUP BY new_road.nummer) new_table
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT old_road.nummer, SUM(ST_length(old_road.geom)) FROM old_road_table.old_road GROUP BY old_road.nummer) old_table
ON new_road.nummer = old_road.nummer

Comment: are they both on the same Database? are road_table and old_road_table schemas?

Answer (score 0):

Following query should solve the purpose. I didn't run it but the basic idea is result of a query on a table is another table on which you can query again.

```
Select * FROM (SELECT new_road.nummer, SUM(new_road.length) FROM road_table.road GROUP BY new_road.nummer) table1 JOIN (SELECT old_road.nummer, SUM(ST_length(old_road.geom)) FROM old_road_table.old_road GROUP BY old_road.nummer) table2 ON table1.new_road.nummer = table2.old_road.nummer
```

Answer (score 0):

The tricky bit here is that you want to make sure you include all of the keys from both lists.  My favorite way to do this kind of thing is:

```
select * from (
  SELECT distinct new_road.nummer as nummer from road_table.road
  union
  SELECT distinct old_road.nummer as nummer FROM old_road_table.old_road
) allkeys
left join
(
  SELECT new_road.nummer as nummer, SUM(new_road.length) as nlen
  FROM road_table.road GROUP BY new_road.nummer
) n 
  on allkeys.nummer = n.nummer
left join 
(
  SELECT old_road.nummer as nummer, SUM(ST_length(old_road.geom)) as olen
  FROM old_road_table.old_road GROUP BY old_road.nummer
) o
  on allkeys.nummer = o.nummer
```

The first subquery builds a list of all keys, then you join to both of your queries from there.  There's nothing wrong with an outer join, but I find this easier to manage if you have to include 3 or more tables.  If you had to include another table it would just be one more union in allkeys and one more left join to that table.